# SAP PO 7.5-Interface from TMS to SAP S/4HANA (inbound). IDOC XML to standard enterprise service to be enhanced with 2 new fields

Tags: tms, sap-pi, s4hana

I am working in SAP PO 7.5 in a TMS interface from TMS to SAP S/4HANA (inbound). It is a IDOC XML (XML file) to standard enterprise service (`TrasaportatiOrderGenericRequest_IN`) which needs to be enhanced by appending 2 new fields.

For N stops (`E1TPSLS-LSQNUM`), (N-1) stages need to be populated with fields under each stage to take values depending on loading/unloading location of deliveries. I am unable to generate `ReqeustedUnloadedDateTime` and `ExpectedArrivalDateTime` fields in each stage with given conditions of loading and unloading.

This is core TMS scenario. Can anyone please help me in it. Do I use any UDF to handle the occurrence and the queue with the given condition. Please help.

Screenshots attached.

Image1: [image: source-IDOC XML structure]

Image2: [image: target-service structure]

Image3: [image: target-stage generate]

Image4: [image: mapping logic]